# Ghost Android emulators starting by themselves

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I noticed that Android Studio (and adb) sometimes show that I have one or more Android emulators running although I didn't start any of them:

[image: Device choose]

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5670   host
emulator-5640   host
```

It becomes somewhat inconvenient when I use adb on the command line and must specify the device each time with `-d` because it says that multiple devices are running.

Why are they starting (what is triggering this)? Can it be disabled?

Android Studio version: 1.5.1 (on Windows 10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an emulator bug, 
try to restart the ADB process

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/adt-dev/4Qbchil3Tcw/VnRhfh-zAgAJ